# Get site to align symmetrically on iPhone

Tags: iphone, html, css, wordpress, mobile

The iPhone is showing an extra space to the left of the site I'm working on that isn't to the right. Any help for why this is? This site is a heavily modified version of the Twenty Eleven WordPress theme. URL is: http://www.picturesquestudios.com/dennis

Answer (score 3):

Try playing with viewports until you get it the way you want it.

Here's an introduction: http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/an-introduction-to-meta-viewport-and-viewport/